# Stripe creates token on Android

Tags: android, callback, token, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

We are trying to create a stripe token from a credit card on our android application, but when we call stripe.createToken it does nothing, it doesn't enter onSuccess nor onError methods in the listener. Our code is the following:

```
private void getStripeToken(Card card) {
    Stripe stripe = null;
    try {
        stripe = new Stripe(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.stripe_public_key));
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    stripe.createToken(card, new TokenCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception error) {
            stripeError = error.getLocalizedMessage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
            stripeToken = token;
        }
    });
}
```

When getStripeToken is finished, stripeError and stripeToken are null. Where are the mistake? Thanks

Comment: problem is in stripe_public_key

Comment: Make sure the card is validated also by calling validateCard() in the card instance. But like the previous comment says i am pretty sure You are not using the corect key . For testing You need the publishable key and for production You need to use the live key.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your `getStripeToken` method, the values are going to be unchanged because `createToken` is an asynchronous action -- that's why you have to give it a callback.

So, if you use `createToken`, you must be on the UI thread (because it uses a `AsyncTask` to make that call, and you should expect your values to be updated whenever the network call is done.

If you want the values to be updated at the end of your method call, use [`createTokenSynchronous`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android#createtokensynchronous), but be sure to only do so off the main thread.